# Are people who answer the questions mostly native English speakers?

Tags: discussion

I'm sorry if this questions are not supposed to be posted here. But I was really wondering about this.
I'm a non native speaker who is suffering from English and I was really glad to find this site cause I really needed someone who could answer my questions related to English especially from native speakers who can intuitively tell if a usage is natural or not.

I was wondering if people who answer the questions are mostly native speakers.

Thank you!

Comment: IMHO, I believe that native speakers are not always necessarily the best people who can answer a given question on ELL. This may sound a bit too strong, but I humbly believe so. It's true that native speakers have several advantages, but so do non-native speakers. In my humble opinion, two groups of people who can answer your questions best are native speakers who understand your first language and non-native speakers who share the same first language with you and have achieved a certain level of proficiency. (A right mindset and good teaching/explanation skill would be a big plus.)

Comment: Related: [Requests for native speakers to answer questions](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/904/3281).

Comment: @Damkerng T. I see your point! I think so too but I was just wondering! Thanks anyway:)

Comment: You're welcome! BTW, welcome to ELL!

Comment: Ordinarily, you'll get a mix of both. Sometimes it's hard to tell which is which. If you want both perspectives, [avoid accepting an answer prematurely](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer).

Comment: +1 for "suffering from English".  As a parent with children learning to read and write, I feel this.

Comment: I am a native speaker miserably afflicted with English. I blame ... England?